# Can't find a way to customize Mutter under elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, mutter

I just installed elementary OS, and I would like to have some options to customize the effects like I could do with Compiz. However, I couldn't find a settings panel related to Mutter.

Is there a GUI utility I should install ?

Comment: Albeit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/80578) is asked wrt. Ubuntu, I think the answer still applies here.  Try `gconf-editor` or another WM.

Answer (score 3):

You can change some of the effects and customize by using

```
    dconf-editor
```

if you have a look in org/pantheon/ and go through available options.